# how to add specific enum values to list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, enums, c#-6.0

I have following enum and  I want only C, E , F, H in the list

```
public enum myEnum{   
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H
}
```

I have tried following and it will give all the enums

```
var listOfEnums = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>().ToList();
```

Comment: If you want to be able to filter a list, you have to have some characteristic to filter on. In this case, you have none. You have no choice but to hard-code the list. The alternative would be to add a custom attribute to those fields and filter on that. That's changing the type though, which may not really be appropriate and also makes the filter code more complex.

Comment: Why can't you add C, E , F, H to the list one by one?

Comment: You can add `.Where(x => x == myEnum.C || x == myEnum.E || x == myEnum.F || x == myEnum.H)` to the linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try the following method:
If you want to have the  `C, E , F, H` fields

```
var result = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>()
            .Select(x => new { C = myEnum.C, E = myEnum.E, F = myEnum.F , H = myEnum.H })
            .ToList();
```

If you want to filter `C, E , F, H` fields:

```
var result = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>()
            .Where(x => x == myEnum.C || x == myEnum.E || x == myEnum.F || x == myEnum.H)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use attributes to retrieve only values that you want.

```
var listOfEnums = Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(myEnum))
    .Cast<myEnum>()
    .Where(e => e.AttributeOfTypeExists<UsableInListAttribute>())
    .ToList();

public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static bool AttributeOfTypeExists<T>(this Enum enumVal) 
        where T : Attribute
    {
        var type = enumVal.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
        return memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false).Length > 0;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class UsableInListAttribute : Attribute { }

public enum myEnum {
    A,
    B,
    [UsableInList]
    C,
    D,
    [UsableInList]
    E,
    [UsableInList]
    F,
    G,
    [UsableInList]
    H
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a pattern that you're trying to match? Why not just try:

```
var listOfEnums = { myEnum.C, myEnum.E, myEnum.F, myEnum.H };
```

Comment: This answer would be ideal if you popped a `new List<myEnum>()` in there.